# Rebus.Async with SimpleInjector Request/Reply MessageCouldNotBeDispatchedToAnyHandlersException

Tags: c#, simple-injector, rebus

I'm using Rebus.Async to reply a processing data to WebApi request using command CQRS.

**1. I registered bus with the following configuration:**

```cs
public static IContainerRegistry RegisterRebusInMemory(
    this IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
    switch (_containerAdapter)
    {
        default: // SimpleInjector
            return RegisterRebusInMemoryWithSimpleInjectorContainer(containerRegistry);
    }
}

private static IContainerRegistry RegisterRebusInMemoryWithSimpleInjectorContainer(
    IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
    var rebusQueue = "rebusMessages";

    Container container = (Container)containerRegistry.Container;

    RegisterRebus(containerRegistry);

    container.ConfigureRebus(
        configurer => configurer
            .Logging(l => l.Console())
            .Serialization(s => s.UseNewtonsoftJson(NewtonsoftSettings, Encoding.UTF8))
            .Options(o =>
            {
                o.EnableSynchronousRequestReply();
                o.SetNumberOfWorkers(1);
                o.SetMaxParallelism(1);
            })
            .Transport(t => t.UseInMemoryTransport(new InMemNetwork(), rebusQueue))
            .Routing(r =>
            {
                r.TypeBased()
                    .MapAssemblyOf<IDomainNotification>(rebusQueue)
                    .MapAssemblyOf<DefaultReplyCommand>(rebusQueue)
                    .MapCommands(rebusQueue)
                    .MapEvents(rebusQueue);
            })
            .Sagas(sagas => sagas.StoreInMemory())
            .Subscriptions(s => s.StoreInMemory())
            .Start()
    );

    return containerRegistry;
}
```

**2. I create a Handle to use with request/reply:**

```cs
public class MyCommandHandler : CommandHandler, IHandleMessages<MyCommand>
{
    ...

    public async Task Handle(MyCommand message)
    {
       DefaultReplyCommand defaultReply = new DefaultReplyCommand(message.AggregateId);
       
       // Do some stuffs
       
       await _bus.Reply(_reply);
    }
    
    ...
}
```

**3. When I send the reply with await _bus.Reply(_reply) throw the following exception:**

> [WRN] Rebus.Retry.ErrorTracking.InMemErrorTracker (Rebus 1 worker 1): Unhandled exception 1 (FINAL) while handling message with ID "request-reply_3452be37-fdfd-4115-89a2-504b4feae22f" Rebus.Exceptions.MessageCouldNotBeDispatchedToAnyHandlersException: Message with ID request-reply_3452be37-fdfd-4115-89a2-504b4feae22f and type AgroHUB.Application.Cattle.Commands.CattleOperation.MoveCattleOperationCommand, AgroHUB.Application.Cattle could not be dispatched to any handlers (and will not be retried under the default fail-fast settings)

```
at Rebus.Pipeline.Receive.DispatchIncomingMessageStep.Process(IncomingStepContext context, Func`1 next)
at Rebus.Sagas.LoadSagaDataStep.Process(IncomingStepContext context, Func`1 next)
at Rebus.Pipeline.Receive.ActivateHandlersStep.Process(IncomingStepContext context, Func`1 next)
at Rebus.Internals.ReplyHandlerStep.Process(IncomingStepContext context, Func`1 next)
at Rebus.Pipeline.Receive.HandleRoutingSlipsStep.Process(IncomingStepContext context, Func`1 next)
at Rebus.Pipeline.Receive.DeserializeIncomingMessageStep.Process(IncomingStepContext context, Func`1 next)
at Rebus.DataBus.ClaimCheck.HydrateIncomingMessageStep.Process(IncomingStepContext context, Func`1 next)
at Rebus.Pipeline.Receive.HandleDeferredMessagesStep.Process(IncomingStepContext context, Func`1 next)
at Rebus.Retry.FailFast.FailFastStep.Process(IncomingStepContext context, Func`1 next)
at Rebus.Retry.Simple.SimpleRetryStrategyStep.DispatchWithTrackerIdentifier(Func`1 next, String identifierToTrackMessageBy, ITransactionContext transactionContext, String messageId, String secondLevelMessageId)
```

**Cenario**

The Rebus.Async works with native C# Dependency Injection (service.AddScope), but when I change de Cointainer to use Simple Injector the reply doesn't work anymore.

There's some extra configuration to use Rebus.Async with Simple Injector?

Comment: It looks like there is no handler for `MoveCattleOperationCommand` registered in the IoC container.

Comment: Did you call `container.Register(typeof(IHandleMessages<>), assembly)` or something similar?

Comment: Ooops. My bad. I forgot to register handlers with `typeof(IHandleMessages<>)`. I changed the code from `handlers.ForEach(hdl => containerRegistry.Register(hdl, hdl))` to the following `containerRegistry.Register(typeof(IHandleMessages<>), handlers)` and the handler was successfully consumed. Thanks @Steven :)

Comment: You should thank @mookid8000 as well. His comment triggered me.

Comment: Sure. Thanks @mookid8000 for the answer and, extending greetings, for this awesome rebus project!